# Highlight modified cells and clear highlight before exit

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to highlight cells that are modified and before the sheet is closed, remove the highlighting. Typically the cells that will be changed are always in one column. I've been reading the developer reference and playing in vba all day. Despite my best efforts I can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a string of code that highlights any targeted cell:

```
Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
```

I was thinking of making an array that recorded targeted cells and on a BeforeClose event, clearing the formatting based on the arrays values. Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read about `Worksheet_Change`

Answer (score 0):

Include the following event macros in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

Comment: Er, 2 things `1` User wants to color cells in only one column `2` The deactivate event will remove the color when the worksheet is deactivated which is not what the user wants. OP has to use BeforeClose event as mentioned in the question...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't know how to close a **Sheet,** only a **Workbook**

Comment: `@SiddharthRout I don't know how to close a Sheet, only a Workbook`I never said anything about `Closing` the sheet :) I was referring to the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event ;) as the other poster mentioned in his answer...

Comment: Changing `Worksheet_Deactivate()` to `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` is functional. Although it indiscriminately resets cell color, it is acceptable. Currently it resets the cells of whatever sheet you happen to have open when BeforeClose is triggered. If you don't have any other color formatting in the workbook it will work.  I'm going to work on targeting it to a specific worksheet rather than the entire workbook. workbookbookworkworkworkbook

Comment: Annnnd changing it back to `Worksheet_Deactivate()` made it do what I wanted in the first place. I didn't realize what it that switching sheets was deactivating them. So this is still very functional so long as I don't have any other color formatting in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public workrange As Range

 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRangeName", RefersTo:="Sheet1!$A$1"

        Set workrange = Range("MyRangeName")

        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)

        Set workrange = Union(workrange, Target.Address)

 End Sub

 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim cell As Variant

        For Each cell In workrange
            If cell.Interior.Color <> RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
               cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next

  End Sub
```

should do what you want, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following code and it works on my side:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Add this to each required worksheet

Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)

If HighlightedCells = "" Then
    HighlightedCells = Target.Address
Else
    HighlightedCells = HighlightedCells & "," & Target.Address
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 'For the Workbook. Alter and repeat the line below for each required worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(HighlightedCells).Style = "Normal"

End Sub
```

---

```
Global HighlightedCells As String 'Add this to a new module
```

Comment: Getting subscript out of range error on 

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(HighlightedCells).Style = "Normal" `